# Pandas: How to set hour of a datetime from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a `dataframe` including a `datetime` column for date and a column for hour.

like this:

```
min hour    date    
0   0   2020-12-01  
1   5   2020-12-02  
2   6   2020-12-01
```

I need a `datetime` column including both date and hour.

like this :

```
min hour    date        datetime
0   0   2020-12-01  2020-12-01 00:00:00
0   5   2020-12-02  2020-12-02 05:00:00 
0   6   2020-12-01  2020-12-01 06:00:00
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [`np.timedelta64`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic):

```
df['datetime'] = df['date'] + df['hour'].apply(lambda x: np.timedelta64(x, 'h'))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   min  hour       date            datetime
0    0     0 2020-12-01 2020-12-01 00:00:00
1    1     5 2020-12-02 2020-12-02 05:00:00
2    2     6 2020-12-01 2020-12-01 06:00:00
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
In [393]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

In [396]: df['datetime'] = df['date'] +  pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'], unit='h')
    
In [405]: df
Out[405]: 
   min  hour       date            datetime
0    0     0 2020-12-01 2020-12-01 00:00:00
1    1     5 2020-12-02 2020-12-02 05:00:00
2    2     6 2020-12-01 2020-12-01 06:00:00
```

Comment: Be aware that you may get unexpected results around daylight saving transitions when you are using a time zone. For example `pd.Timestamp('2033-03-27 0:00', tz='CET') + pd.to_timedelta(23, unit='h')`gives `Timestamp('2033-03-28 00:00:00+0200', tz='CET')` and not as you might expect `Timestamp(2022-03-27 23:00:00+0100)`
Or `pd.Timestamp('2022-03-27 0:00', tz='CET') + pd.to_timedelta(2, unit='h')` results in `Timestamp('2022-03-27 03:00:00+0200', tz='CET')`

Answer (score 0):

In the first question it is not clear the data type of columns, so i thought they are
in **date** (not pandas) and he want the **datetime** version.

If this is the case so, solution is similar to the previous, but using a different constructor.

```
from datetime import datetime
df['datetime'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime(x.date.year, x.date.month, x.date.day, int(x['hour']), int(x['min'])), axis=1)
```